# Element disappearing on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to do some things with Jquery and there seems to be something going wrong.

first off some code,

my HTML,

```
<a href="#" onclick="return false;" class="scrollToTop"></a>
```

my CSS,

```
.scrollToTop {
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 45px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #CFCFCF;
    background-image: url(../img/upActive.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 61px;
    right: 30px;
    transition: opacity 2s ease-in;
}

.scrollToTop:hover {
    background-color: #989898;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: opacity 2s ease-in;
}
```

My Jquery,

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var hidden = $('.scrollToTop');
    hidden.hide();

    // Check to see if the window is top if not then display button
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
            hidden.show(1000);
        } else {
            hidden.hide(1000);
        }
    });

    // Click event to scroll to top
    $('.scrollToTop').click(function(e) {
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: 0
        }, 800);
        return false;
    });

});
```

JSfiddle: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vasilenicusor/rp9kLwLc/2/) (thanks vasilenicusor)

The problem is that all the buttons in my project dissapear after they have been clicked. I can see the ring arround them that my browser puts there, but the fysical button dissapears.. 
This problem does not seem to happen in the fiddle (the code is not working at all in the fiddle).

Does anyone know how I should fix this and maby what is the problem? I guess something in the Jquery code is making the buttons do this. (there are about 8 Jquery files with 100+ lines of code, most of them are library's).

The code below does not work. I've tried it.

```
(function(e) 
{ 
    e.preventDefault; 
});
```

Thanks in advance!

**Thanks Chun for your answer!** 
But what seems to be the problem in my code is there seems to be some library that is causing this "dissapear" effect when there is a "href" is the link. Removing the "href" temporally solved my problem.

Comment: Can I ask you to post a fiddle with the buttons so that we can see what happens ? Right now all I can see is a dot in the bottom right corner that doesn't do anything at all when clicked. Also what browser are you using?

Comment: In your fiddle you need to select the jQuery in the top-left drop-down 'Frameworks and Libraries' - your example seems to work fine then. 

But the answer to your problem is that the button (which I presume is the scroll to top button) will be hidden when you scroll to the top because that is what your code does - if the scroll distance to to top of the page is less than 100px then the buttons will be hidden.

Comment: I have updated your JSFIddle example bu adding jquery extension and all loks to work fine https://jsfiddle.net/vasilenicusor/rp9kLwLc/2/ . Can you give us a detailed page?

Comment: I could not able to find the problem https://jsfiddle.net/rp9kLwLc/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just use `href="javascript:void(0)"` instead of `href="#" onclick="return false;"`

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="scrollToTop"></a>
    <!-- OR better -->
<a class="scrollToTop"></a>
    <!-- OR even better -->
<span class="scrollToTop"></span>
```

and just give `scrollToTop` the attributes of a link with CSS for the markup without `href`, like:

```
.scrollToTop { cursor: pointer; color: blue; }
```

Having `<a href="#" onclick="myJsFunc();">Link</a>` or `<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="myJsFunc();">Link</a>` or whatever else that contains an `onclick` attribute - was okay a couple of years ago, though now it can be a bad practice. Here's why:

1. It promotes the practice of obtrusive Javascript - which has turned out to be difficult to maintain and difficult to scale. More on this in **[Unobtrusive JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript)**.
2. There are now better, easier, and more maintainable and scalable ways of accomplishing the desired result.

### The unobtrusive Javascript way

Just don't have a `href` attribute at all! Any good CSS reset would take care of the missing default cursor style, so that is a non-issue. Then in case you have a Javascript functionality to attach using graceful and unobtrusive  best practices - which are more maintainable as your Javascript logic stays in Javascript, instead of in your markup - which is essential when you start developing large scale Javascript applications.

```
<a class="scrollToTop">Cancel this action</a>

// Cancel click event
$('.scrollToTop').click(function(){
    alert('Cancel action occurs!');
});

.scrollToTop { cursor: pointer; color: blue; }
.scrollToTop:hover { text-decoration: underline; }
```

---

### Update

I've also forget to say, change your **scroll to top** function for this instead:

```
// Click to scroll to top
$(".scrollToTop").click(function() {
    $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, "slow");
});
```

Check out jsfiddle example here: **https://jsfiddle.net/x1x9pmpx**

Comment: Thanks for the update chun, but adding "slow" instead of "800" does not seem to work. The page scrolls up in about 100 ms instead of arround 800 ms..

Comment: the relevant part was not changing `800` to `slow`, you can leave it like that if you want it. The relevant part was removing the `(e)` event from the `.click(function(e)` that was just standing there and it's not necessary... I think that exchanging `a href` tags for a `<span>` or a `<div>` should fix the problem.

Comment: I can agree on that. Thanks for the tip Chun!

Comment: I would like to know why it's always argued that it's best to keep javascript out of the markup. I feel like a declarative html syntax is easier to understand and maintain instead of combing through files of javascript