# Jquery scrolldown css not working

Tags: jquery, html, css, selected

Ok, so after fixing the dissapear problem ([Element disappearing on click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30248166/element-disappearing-on-click?noredirect=1#comment48610417_30248166)) I have a new problem that, I think, is related to this problem.

When I click on a header link the page scrolls down, with Jquery, to the right article. This function works great. But an other function changes css of the according button on position on the page (`scrolltop()`). This function also works. But when I clicked the button my css does not change. It makes my button a white link with a gray "clicked" border arround it (done by the browser). Only when I click anywhere else on the screen (to remove the "active" button state) the button changes color.

I could not replicate the problem with JSFiddle ([Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3rg1q17e/2/)) so here are some images describing the problem above:

**This is my menu:**

[image: Normal]

**This is when I hover my menu:**

[image: hover]

**This is when I selected "over ons":**

[image: Selected]

**And this is when I unselect the button:**

[image: Unselected]

Now the question is, how can I give my selected button (image 3) the same css as my unselected button (image 4)?

This style `text-decoration:none` does not work. 
Also using the `:active` css attribute does not work.

I cannot seem to find a solution on the internet. Am I missing something?

**Solution**

Thanks Drops for this answer! 
`:focus` did the trick. Never heard of it before, but it worked. Thanks!

Comment: `foo:selected{text-decoration:none}` ?

Comment: Take a look at css pseudo class `:focus` and `outline` property.

Comment: write in css outline:none;

Comment: @Drops Could you add your set your answer in an answer and not in a comment? Then i can flag it as the best answer :)

Comment: @Mr.wiseguy here you go, also I've added link to excellent answer about difference between `:focus` and `:active`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should take a look at CSS pseudo-class `:focus`, here are [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:focus).

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1677990/what-is-the-difference-between-focus-and-active) will tell you more about difference between `:focus` and `:active` pseudo-classes.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Create a class `noSelect` and assign it to all of those buttons. This will prevent it from being highlighted

```
.noSelect {
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}
```

**Edit**
If that is the case then try setting

```
a:active {
    outline:none 
}
```

Comment: Assigning this class to the buttons (which are <a></a> tags) does not work.

Comment: The solution was :focus 
Outline:node didn't do the trick for me.

Comment: Oh, nice one! You should post an answer to your question then for others to see

Answer (score 0):

The css element `:focus` is the answer tot a clicked element. By using `.menuButton:focus` I managed to style the clicked button.

Due to the scrolling and dynamically change button styles (my buttons get active state depending on the page position) I also needit to remove the focus right after it was initiated.

This can be done by: `$(':focus').blur()` (Jquery).

*Credits go to Drops for the `:focus` element.*